# Do these two lines mean same?

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

I was wondering if this two lines mean same?

```
@Size(min = 0, max = 50)
String a;

@Size(max = 50)
String b;
```

This annotation is part of `javax.validation.constraints.Size`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the meaning is the same.
As you can see in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html#min--) the Default value of `min` is 0

> min
>
> public abstract int min
>
> Returns:size the element must be higher or
> equal to
>
> Default:0

Answer (score 2):

Of course they do, because default value for `min` is `0` in interface [javax.validation.constraints.Size](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/javax/validation/constraints/Size.java#Size.min%28%29)

```
 int min() default 0;
```

Comment: You should add a Link to the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html#min()

Answer (score 2):

They are they same because `min` has a default value of 0.

Refer: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html